# Why I can not find number of bigrams = number_of_words - 1?

Tags: r, n-gram

I am writing an R script to find bigrams.

I have a string of 4157 words.

Now, using `stylo`, I am taking bigrams in my vector as below.

```
library(stylo)

allBi <- txt.to.words(myLines)
myBigrams <- make.ngrams(allBi, ngram.size = 2)
```

That only returns 4120 bigrams. What is the problem?

Comment: if i am taking 5 words , by using this code , i am getting 4 bi grams. But when i am taking too many words like 4157 , i am getting some less number of bi grams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you did no testing to try to figure out what's going on.

From the tests below, one (or more) of your 4,127 entries in `myLines` seems to not actually contain a "word" as the `style` package sees words:

```
library(stylo)
```

This file has 235,886 legit words on my OS X system:

```
words <- readLines("/usr/share/dict/words")
```

Now, perform tests to see if there is anything related to vector length impacting `make.ngrams` or (more likely) `txt.to.words`. NOTE: I did not feel like waiting a cpl minutes for `make.ngrams` to crank through sequences up to 235,886 so i max it at 20,000 which is well above your 4,120:

```
all(sapply(seq(from=2, to=20000, by=100), function(i) {
  return(i - length(make.ngrams(txt.to.words(words[1:i]), ngram.size=2))==1)
}))
# [1] TRUE
```

So, it is not a vector size problem. Could it be a *lack of actual words in the vector* problem? Let's test that:

```
# inject some badness
words[4] <- sprintf("  , %s - ", words[4])
words[30] <- "//"
words[900] <- "-1--1-"
words[4000]  <- ".."
```

and try it again:

```
all(sapply(seq(from=2, to=20000, by=100), function(i) {
  return(i - length(make.ngrams(txt.to.words(words[1:i]), ngram.size=2))==1)
}))
# [1] FALSE
```

Let's see what `txt.to.words` does it do to real "badness":

```
txt.to.words(words[c(4, 30, 900, 4000)])
# [1] "aal"
```

Use this to find the entries in `words` with no letters:

```
which(grepl("^[^[:alpha:]]+$", words))
# [1]   30  900 4000
```

Testing FTW (and it's not too much work to actually perform some tests when things aren't going as expected).